# apt-get ignore-missing does not work

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm testing the `ignore-missing` option with apt-get, but it does not actually work:

```
# apt install -y --ignore-missing xfce4-terminal amule
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package amule is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'amule' has no installation candidate
```

What's the right option here?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Similar question (also unanswered): https://serverfault.com/questions/875024/apt-get-install-with-not-available-packages